# Why does this make my prime-generating algorithm take longer?

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, primes

I'm trying to find all primes below 1 000 000. As all non-primes can be factorised into primes, my method is to start my list of primes as [2, 3] and then run through every number up to 1 000 000. If a number is divisible by any number in prime_list, then it's not prime, and I move onto the next number. If this number isn't divisible by any number in prime_list, then it must be prime, and it gets added to this list.

To try and make this more efficient, I added a statement to only check if a number in question is divisible by values below the square root of this number. I thought this would cut out a lot of computation time but it actually makes my program take longer. Can anyone explain why?

Here's my code:

```
import math

import time
start_time = time.time()

prime = [2, 3]

def prime_checker(a):
    for j in prime:
        if j < (int(math.sqrt(a)) +1 ):     /// without this line, the program runs faster
            if a % j == 0:
                return False

for i in range (2, 100000):
    if prime_checker(i) != False:
        prime.append(i)

print prime[-1]

print "Time taken = ", time.time() - start_time
```

Comment: You are repeatedly performing an expensive operation that is independent of the value of `j`. Compute `math.sqrt(a)` *once* outside the loop.

Comment: See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: You can probably do a little better: keep an index to the largest prime which, when squared, doesn't exceed the currently tested number. When you go from i to i+1, you can update this index by a single square-root-free test. Then you immediately know the range of divisors to be tried.

Answer (score 3):

To further speed up your algorithm, note that 2 is the only even prime.  All other even numbers are composite.  You already have `prime = [2, 3]` so you can start searching at 5 (4 is not prime) and only check odd numbers:

```
for i in range (5, 100000, 2):
    if prime_checker(i) != False:
        prime.append(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

The time you spend repeatedly calculating the square root of `a` overwhelms whatever you save by skipping larger primes. Compute the square root *once*, which in my test is 10x faster than calculating it repeatedly (and about 3x faster than leaving the line out altogether).

```
def prime_checker(a):
    limit = int(math.sqrt(a)) + 1
    for j in prime:
        if j > limit:
            break
        if a % j == 0:
            return False
    return True

for i in range (2, 100000):
    if prime_checker(i):
        prime.append(i)
```

Comment: You don't actually need to compute the square root at all; instead, square the prime you're testing against.

Comment: One square root is still going to be faster once you have to square more than 5 primes or so in the body of the loop.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a square root costs a lot more than five multiplies.

Comment: Possibly. However, the point is that for a prime number `a`, you would need `O(lg (sqrt(a)))` multiplications, which is probably *not* faster than a single square root of `a`.

Comment: for a *prime* `a` you'd need *O( sqrt(a) / lg(sqrt(a)))* multiplications with the optimal trial division algorithm, but *O(a / lg(a))* with OP's. i.e., the OP is *not* skipping the larger primes. Even your code isn't. :)

Comment: Ah, OK, that last point I can fix. I'm not sure figuring the break-even point between squaring primes and just calculating a single square-root is going to be worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

"If this number isn't divisible by any number in prime_list" *that is not greater than this number's square root*, then it is a prime.

And once you've hit a prime above the square root, *all the rest of them will be so* as well. We know this *in advance*.

The point is not to check whether to avoid *each* extraneous check, but to **prevent all of them**, in advance. This will speed up your code 100x, if not 1000x or even more.

In other words the real problem isn't the repeated calculation of the `sqrt`, but the incorrect handling of the limiting condition. With the correct handling of the limiting condition, even the repeated calculation of `sqrt` shouldn't matter much.

> and the correct way is: break out from the loop as soon as possible, i.e. immediately when the first prime above the square root is reached; possibly by directly returning `True` right then and there.

Comment: I think he is aware of this, which is why he added the comparison to the square root. The problem was he was doing too many square-root calculations, which was more expensive than just checking the too-large primes.

Comment: @chepner what he's doing is ~ *k^2*; what I propose is ~ *k^1.5*, in *k* primes produced. Perhaps I was a bit too cryptic. I've edited for clarity.

Comment: IOW with the correct handling of the sqrt condition, even the repeated calculation of sqrt shouldn't matter much.

Answer (score 0):

Using `**0.5` instead of `math.sqrt` also tends to be exponentially faster:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> print(timeit.timeit('math.sqrt(1830374)', setup='import math', number=10000))
0.0020401941434329274
>>> print(timeit.timeit('1830374**0.5', number=10000))
0.00015091430498159752
```

Chepner's code is the right answer though, just don't forget to iterate like rossum said. Iteration the way he stated will literally save you half a million calls (though, they will break quickly with Chepner's algorithm, that's still a lot of wasted time).

Answer (score 0):

Your solution consumes `O(N**1.5)` time. To faster it, use [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). It's time complexity is `O(NloglogN))`.

```py
n = 10 ** 5
sieve = [True] * n
sieve[0] = sieve[1] = False

for i in range(2, n):
    if sieve[i]:
        for j in range(i + i, n, i):
            sieve[j] = False

primes = []
for i, j in enumerate(sieve):
    if j:
        primes.append(i)
```